# Genymotion unable to start because of VBoxManage error?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, android, emulators

I installed VirtualBox and Genymotion on Ubuntu 18.04

But, when I run Genymotion it starts to boot and it shows me that it's not able to find VirtualBox, but looking at logs this fails:

```
2019-03-23T21:38:36+01:00 [Genymotion:16700] [critical] [VBox] Return code: 1
2019-03-23T21:38:36+01:00 [Genymotion:16700] [critical] [VBox] Output command: "0%...
    Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
    VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
    VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
    VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
    VBoxManage: error: Context: \"RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg*)\" at line 94 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp"
2019-03-23T21:38:36+01:00 [Genymotion:16700] [critical] [VBox] [createHostOnlyInterface] Failed to create interface
2019-03-23T21:38:36+01:00 [Genymotion:16700] [critical] [VBox] "Fail to load vboxmanage plugin from /home/dinko/genymotion/plugins/"
2019-03-23T21:38:36+01:00 [Genymotion:16700] [critical] Unable to find VM Engine. Plugin loading aborted.
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Welcome, `members vboxusers` sould print `dinko` , if not add the user to `vboxusers`: `sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers dinko`

Comment: I will check that later. Thank you